# tokenizing text by separating the punctuation from the words but not abbreviations and apostrophes

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I have input text that I want to tokenize by separating punctuation from words while accounting for abbreviations and apostrophes. I'm using python and the nltk library but I think my regex isn't correct as I'm still getting the output wrong.

```
# coding: utf-8
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import *

text = "\"Predictions suggesting that large changes in weight will 
accumulate indefinitely in response to small sustained lifestyle 
modifications rely on the half-century-old 3,500 calorie rule, which 
equates a weight alteration of 2.2 lb to a 3,500 calories cumulative 
deficit or increment,\" write the study authors Dr. Jampolis, Dr. 
Chaudry, and Prof. Harlen, from N.P.C Clinic in OH. The 3,500- calorie 
rule \"predicts that a person who increases daily energy expenditure by 
100 calories by walking 1 mile per day\" will lose 50 pounds over five 
years, the authors say. But the true weight loss is only about 10 
pounds if calorie intake doesn't increase, \"because changes in mass 
... alter the energy requirements of the body’s make-up.\" \"This is a 
myth, strictly speaking, but the smaller amount of weight loss achieved 
with small changes is clinically significant and should not be 
discounted,\" says Dr. Melina Jampolis, CNN diet and fitness expert."

print(regexp_tokenize(text, pattern='(?:(?!\d)\w)+|\S+') )
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: I am unclear as to what your desired output is

Comment: The desired output would be tokenized text, but without separating words that have punctuation like apostrophes (doesn't stays as one token), and abbreviations as well ( N.P.C. stays as one token)

Comment: So you basically just want to remove "/", "\", "," and quotation marks?

Comment: yes, and "..." sorry if this is trivial, I'm trying to learn how to use the nltk library, and some of the little things are confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It makes sense to just use a re.sub here to replace any of those undesirable punctuations with nothing (i.e. '').

```
s = 'Insert your text here'

new = re.sub(r'(\"\\\")|(\\\")|[.]{3}|,','', s)

print(new)
```

The difficult part with this regex is escaping all of the backslashes. To break this down:

```
(\"\\\")
```

Locates any "\"

```
(\\\")
```

Locates any \"

```
[.]{3}
```

Locates any ...

```
,
```

Locates any ,

The pipes serve as 'or' operators. Hopefully this meets all of your requirements.